# Validate Response Json with Java Model Class

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, validation

I am working on a Spring boot application.I consume a Restful API and I get a json response which I deserialize.

Problem is the API responds with incorrect fields and some of the values which should not be null are sent as null values. Due to this when I validate the deserialized object using `org.springframework.validation.Validator.validate` method, it raises errors. Worst thing is, it does not mention what are the incorrect fields in the json. The API response should be fixed, but I want to know where the json does not adhere to the model class.

How can I validate the json and know what are the fields which violates constrains such as null, incorrect property name in json ? Thanks in advance.

```
public void validate(Object object) {
    BeanPropertyBindingResult result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(object,
            object.getClass().getSimpleName());
    validator.validate(object, result);
    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        return;
    }
    List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    for (FieldError fieldError : result.getFieldErrors()) {
        String field = fieldError.getField();
        String message = fieldError.getDefaultMessage();
        errorMessages.add("Field: " + field + ", Error: " + message);
    }
    String errorMsg = errorMessages.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    if (enabledThrowException) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Incorrectly Declared Fields:\n" + errorMsg);
    }
    log.error(errorMsg);
}
```

This is a part of a quite big model class and model class cannot be changed to adjust to the API response Json.

```
@Data
public class Student {
    @NotNull
    @Schema(description = "Student name.")
    private String name;
    @Nullable
    @Schema(description = "University url.")
    private String url;
    @Nullable
    @Schema(description = "Description")
    private String Description;
}
```